# Report RDLC not show in New Item Panel after installation there is no option report and report wiz visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rdlc

Report RDLC not show in New Item Panel after installation there is no option report and report wiz visual studio 2019

[rdlc not showing in correct form but show codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVCOj.png)

[Report Installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIj5M.png)

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-1-creating-a-report-server-project-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15  Looks like second link (NUGet) need to browse and add your RDLC file to the project.

Comment: its mean now we can't add report in existing projects?

Comment: The reports (RDLC files) are associated with the SQL Server.  So the reports (RDLC files) need to be loaded on the 2019 Server.  You do not need a new RDLC project, just make sure the RDLC files are added to the 2019 Server.  It looks like the NUGet GUI is doing the install in the 2019 Server.  You do not need to use the NuGet GUI, same can be done with SQL Server GUI.  The NuGet and SQL Server GUIs are equivalent.